# node assync function não retorna o dado

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

index.js:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: {username: username, password: password}

})
  .done(data => {
        console.log(data);
});
```

na minha api node:

```
app.post('/login',async  function(req,res){

    email = req.body.username;
    password = req.body.password;

    return await db.find(email,password);

});
```

na função do db:

```
module.exports.find = async function(email,password){
   search(email,password).then(a => {
     return a;
 });


};

function search(email,password){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    table.find({where: {email: email, password:password}}).done(function(data,err){
        if(data != "" && data != null)
          resolve(data);
      });
  });
}
```

A função não retorna o valor pro data embora eu tenha usado o async await para esperar a resposta e só voltar quando tenha pego a mesma, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que você está usando o [express](http://expressjs.com/), você precisa usar o método `send` para retornar os dados ao cliente.

```
app.post('/login',async  function(req,res){

    email = req.body.username;
    password = req.body.password;

    const resultado = await db.find(email,password);

    res.send(resultado)
});
```